# React Native Change splash screen

Tags: android, react-native

I am using expo to use my react native app then creating new  app react-native init app_name then creating apk with Android Studio.

I can change the app icon and splash screen in expo app.json like

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "displayName": "MyApp", 
  "icon": "./images/icon.png",
  "splash": {
    "image": "./aso/splash.png",
    "resizeMode": "contain",
    "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
  }
}
```

It works with expo
But when I add this icon and splash to new react native app nothing happens.
How can I change this two images

Comment: Have you read this? https://docs.expo.io/guides/splash-screens/ I think you might want to move the `splash` section to the expo field

Answer (score 1):

In expo project on 'bare' workflow, follow this link: [SplashScreen](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-splash-screen#-installation-in-bare-react-native-projects)

for 'bare' react-native projects (npx react-native init...), app.json does not have any affect. For splash screen you will have to use 3rd party plugins like react-native-splash-screen or react-native-bootsplash.

Comment: I see, thank you, is this is the only way, it's a simple thing

Comment: @devbamboo you can create a Splash Screen in JS but it wouldn't be native and will load after the parse of JS. I recommend react-native-bootsplash it's native splash screen and fairly easy to set up.